# Extraction of text data from text file using R

Tags: r, excel

How can I extract individual tags automatically using "R" from the following sample text (.txt) file and convert in excel file format where excel Columns will getTag heading like PMID, TI, DP, FAU etc and respective values will be sorted under this headings???

```
PMID- 24579777
OWN - NLM
STAT- Publisher
DA  - 20141210
LR  - 20141210
IS  - 1476-8259 (Electronic)
IS  - 1025-5842 (Linking)
VI  - 18
IP  - 11
DP  - 2015 Aug
TI  - A complete structural performance analysis and modelling of hydroxyapatite
      scaffolds with variable porosity.
PG  - 1225-1237
AB  - The use of hydroxyapatite (HA) scaffolds for bone regeneration is an alternative 
      procedure to treat bone defects due to cancer, other diseases or traumas.
      Although the use of HA has been widely studied in the literature, there are still
      some disparities regarding its mechanical performance. This paper presents a
      complete analysis of the structural performance of porous HA scaffolds based on
      experimental tests, numerical simulations and theoretical studies. HA scaffolds
      with variable porosity were considered and fabricated by the water-soluble
      polymer method, using poly vinyl alcohol as pore former. These scaffolds were
      then characterised by scanning electron microscopy, stereo microscopy, X-ray
      diffraction, porosity analysis and mechanical tests. Different scaffold models
      were proposed and analysed by the finite element method to obtain numerical
      predictions of the mechanical properties. Also theoretical predictions based on
      the (Gibson LJ, Ashby MF. 1988. Cellular solids: structure and properties.
      Oxford: Pergamon Press) model were obtained. Finally the experimental, numerical 
      and theoretical results were compared. From this comparison, it was observed that
      the proposed numerical and theoretical models can be used to predict, with
      adequate accuracy, the mechanical performance of HA scaffolds for different
      porosity values.
FAU - Gallegos-Nieto, Enrique
AU  - Gallegos-Nieto E
AD  - a Facultad de Ingenieria, Centro de Investigacion y Estudios de
      Posgrado,Universidad Autonoma de San Luis Potosi , CP 78290 SLP , Mexico.
FAU - Medellin-Castillo, Hugo I
AU  - Medellin-Castillo HI
FAU - de Lange, Dirk F
AU  - de Lange DF
LA  - ENG
PT  - JOURNAL ARTICLE
DEP - 20140228
TA  - Comput Methods Biomech Biomed Engin
JT  - Computer methods in biomechanics and biomedical engineering
JID - 9802899
OTO - NOTNLM
OT  - compressive strength
OT  - finite element method
OT  - hydroxyapatite
OT  - modulus of elasticity
OT  - porosity
OT  - scaffolds
EDAT- 2014/03/04 06:00
MHDA- 2014/03/04 06:00
CRDT- 2014/03/04 06:00
PHST- 2014/02/28 [aheadofprint]
AID - 10.1080/10255842.2014.889690 [doi]
PST - ppublish
SO  - Comput Methods Biomech Biomed Engin. 2015 Aug;18(11):1225-1237. Epub 2014 Feb 28.
```

Answer (score 1):

Without writing out the entire script, here are the basics of what you could do:

1. Read the file in as a table with " - " as separator `data=read.table('filename',sep="-", row.names=F, col.names=F)`
2. Loop through all the data in the table (for loops would work, or you could use the apply functions) and trim leading/trailing spaces `data[i,j]=gsub("^  *",'',data[i,j])`, `data[i,j]=gsub("  *$",'',data[i,j])`
3. Transpose the data `newData=t(data)`
4. Write to excel spreadsheet (you can also use write.csv as that is excel compatible and built in to R)

   `library(xlsx)
   write.xlsx(newdata, "c:/mydata.xlsx",col.names=F, row.names=F)`

Comment: After using the above command i got following error >data=read.table('sample.txt',sep="-", row.names=F, col.names=F)
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 5 did not have 2 elements
In addition: Warning message:
In read.table("sample.txt", sep = "-", row.names = F, col.names = F) :
  header and 'col.names' are of different lengths

Comment: Ah, yes, I missing that the long text entries are not quoted. In that case you are pretty much stuck writing a line-by-line parser unless you have the option to modify the input format and add quotes around these multi-line entries.